# keyup event not working inside contenteditable:true tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I don't know what the problem is with my code. My `keyup` event is not triggered inside a `contenteditable` tag. Here is my code :

```
 $(document).on( 'keyup' , '#editable_div span' ,function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).removeClass('abc');
                });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2P9t/5/) example

Comment: It's the `contenteditable` that receives the keystroke events, not the spans within it.  Omit the `span` from your selector and your handler fires.  You might need to use the selection API to find the appropriate `span`.

Comment: Please check for responses whenever you ask a question and validate them.

Answer (score -4):

I have updated the fiddle and made this work the way you wanted. Please try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/W2P9t/7/

JS Code:

```
var spansContent  = Array();
$("#editable_div span").each(function(){
   spansContent.push($(this).html()); 
});



    $(document).on( 'keyup' ,function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        for(var i=0;i<spansContent.length;i++)
                        {
                            if($($("#editable_div span")[i]).html()!=  spansContent[i]) {
                            $($("#editable_div span")[i]).removeClass('abc');
                            }
                        }

                    })
```

HTML:

```
<div id="editable_div" contenteditable="true">
    <span class="abc">hello1</span>
    <span>hello2</span>
    <span class="abc">hello3</span>
    <span class="abc">hello4</span>
    <span>hello5</span>
    <span class="abc">hello6</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.abc{color:red;}
```

Comment: dude its working, go to fiddle link . click run and then test!

Comment: may be you are not including jquery in fiddle left panel..i can see it working on my end..whenever a span is edited the red color goes away . This is what was required

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YFJVD/4/
check this fiddle its simple and yet solves the purpose

Comment: what if he has 1000 spans under that div. He wont add the contenteditable=true to each span. You should have made that dynamic.

Comment: also i have not changed his html part and managed to achieve the output through js which is how it should be done.

Comment: i have included js from the panel might be some other issue.